# how to perform action of list of directories listed using for loop?

Tags: linux, for-loop, awk, scripting

I am doing one check to see if a directory is present inside list of below directories. Below is the table listed. This is the only table available about such directories.

> user@root> cat u
>
> Directory  owner  value
>   --------   ----   -----
>   0-0-1-0     Aleks    10
>   0-0-2-0     Ram      23
>   0-0-3-0     mark     43
>   0-0-4-0     Sam      22
>   0-0-5-0     wood     21
>   0-0-6-0     peter    34
>   0-0-7-0     ron      45
>   0-0-8-0     Alic     44
>   0-0-9-0     amber    56
>   0-0-10-0    janny    34
>
> user@root> cat u |grep -Ev "owner|--"|awk '{print $1 }'
>   0-0-1-0
>   0-0-2-0
>   0-0-3-0
>   0-0-4-0
>   0-0-5-0
>   0-0-6-0
>   0-0-7-0
>   0-0-8-0
>   0-0-9-0
>   0-0-10-0

## Query:

I want to login into all the directories from `0-0-1-0` to `0-0-10-0` and perform some action. How can I do that ?

For example I want to validate if `XYZ` directory is present inside all the directories or not.

> user@root>test -d 0-0-1-0/XYZ; if [ "$?" != "0" ];then echo "directory is missing" fi

I think if I can store value of each row incrementally in some variable then issue will be resolved.

Comment: What do you mean login to the directories ?

Comment: just cd and use some random command to validate if the directories are present.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the DIR_NAME_TO_BE_SEARCHED, then you can use following command:

```
find YOUR_STARTING_DIRECTORY -type d -name DIR_NAME_TO_BE_SEARCHED -print
```

example:

```
find . -type d -name test -print
```

explanation:

will find all directories (-type d) starting from your current directory that have their name as test  (-name test) and output them (-print).

and if you don't know the exact DIRECTORY_NAME_TO_BE_SEARCHED, then you can use pattern as well :

```
find YOUR_STARTING_DIRECTORY -type d -name "DIR_NAME_TO_BE_SEARCHED_PATTERN" -print
```

example:

```
find . -type d -name "\*test\*" -print
```

Comment: This is not helping me as I have a list of directories, and inside them I have to search.

Answer (score 0):

You can process your list of files like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for dir in $(awk 'NR>2 {print $1}' $1)
do
   if [[ -d "$dir" ]]
   then
     cd "$dir"
     pwd
     # Do random stuff
   fi
done
```

Run the script like this:

```
./script.sh my_list_of_files
```

If the directory exists it will cd to that directory and run pwd.

One warning though, this script will get a bit confused if any of your directories have a space in them.

Comment: Is there way to give list of directorires from inside the script ,may be using xargs ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: Currently as suggested by you ,I have to pass the list from my_list_of_files.  My concern is , I need to pass the list of files from inside the script, as its being processsed by awk .

Comment: Thats just the name of the file.   In your example it's u.